# StackPanel Horizontal Content Aligement to Center in a dataTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

```
<ComboBox Height="50" Width="90" Name="cmb" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Names}"  BorderThickness="0" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Width="50"    Orientation="Horizontal">

                            </StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.Items>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

C#

```
public class Example
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }

}

List<Example> list = new List<Example>();
Example ex = new Example();
ex.Name = "1";
ex.Names = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
list.Add(ex);

Example ex1 = new Example();
ex1.Name = "2";
ex1.Names = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
list.Add(ex1);

Example ex2 = new Example();
ex2.Name = "3";
ex2.Names = new List<string> { "1" };
list.Add(ex2);

cmb.ItemsSource = list;
```

Hi Here i'm  just adding a ItemsControl.  and a label. as u can see the ItemsControl Binding prop is names value. which have values of 1,2,3 and 1,2 and 1. i need trying to display them like pyramid So how can i set the stack panels content to center?

**Expected**

```
  1     lablevalue
 1 2    lablevalue 
1 2 3   lablevalue
```

**current output**

```
1      lablevalue
1 2    lablevalue
1 2 3  lablevalue
```

Comment: The only way I can think to do this will require replacing the outer `StackPanel` with a `Grid` containing 2 columns, with the first column set to having a `SharedSizeGroup` that you place the "pyramid" rows in.  The second column contains the label.  You will have to wrap the entire thing in another `Grid` with `IsShareSizeScope` set to `true` in the ListBox's `ItemsPanelTemplate`.  It's going to be a pretty complex layout.

Comment: Thanks for that I will try that once

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. using IsSharedsizeScope and SharedSizeGroup which allows sharing column sizes across different grids

```
<StackPanel   Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid Margin="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="1"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="2"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="3"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="15">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="Auto"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="1"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="20">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Button Margin="10" Content="Click Me" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
```